# Why does Json.NET DeserializeObject change the timezone to local time?

Tags: c#, json.net, datetimeoffset

I'm using json.net to deserialize a `DateTimeOffset`, but it is ignoring the specified timezone and converting the datetime to the local offset. For example, given

```
var content = @"{""startDateTime"":""2012-07-19T14:30:00+09:30""}";
```

When deserialised using:

```
var jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings() { DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat, DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.DateTimeOffset, DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.RoundtripKind };
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(content, jsonSerializerSettings);
```

The obj will contain a property containing a `DateTimeOffset` but the value will be `2012-07-19T15:30:00+10:30` i.e. converted to the local timezone instead of preserving the original timezone.

Is there a way to get the value to be parsed as expected so that the resulting `DateTimeOffset` property will match the supplied value?

Comment: Funny thing is that the date/time is actually correct, 14:30 in +9:30 must be 15:30 in +10:30.

Comment: Not sure if there's any relation here, but it seems WCF serialization/deserialization does this trick by default as well. Perhaps the same solution could help you: http://daveonsoftware.blogspot.com/2008/07/wcf-datetime-field-adjusted.html

Comment: Hint for other. Sometimes it's better to use `DateParseHandling.None` to output the date as a `string` and parse yourself.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It seems to be ignoring `DateParseHandling.DateTimeOffset` and is using `DateParseHandling.DateTime`.  I would log an issue here: https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json

Comment: I do not know if this bug has been fixed.

Comment: @PeterRitchie any success resolving this issue? I am using 8.0.3 version but still getting the same issue

Comment: @JasmeetSingh Shows as being fixed on the Newtonsoft site.

Comment: @PeterRitchie yeah I saw that. Problem in my case was there were 2 api's wrapped over one. I had to do the setting changes on the wrapped one. Thanks

Answer (score 16):

Try using this:

```
microsoftDateFormatSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat,
    DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Local
};
var items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<lstObject>>(jsonString, microsoftDateFormatSettings);
```

I don't know if it will work in all cases but for me it did. You can try some other values for `DateTimeZoneHandling` or search for more options on Google.

Comment: Not worked - exception

Comment: Not working , when parsing still recalculate to LocalTime and add local UTC offset

Answer (score 16):

If you're using .NET WebApi you can add the following to the `WebApiConfig.cs` file to handle this globally in your application.

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.DateTimeZoneHandling = 
    Newtonsoft.Json.DateTimeZoneHandling.Local;
```

This will specifically tell the `JsonFormatter` to include and understand the local time zone information when serializing and deserializing a date.

Answer (score 11):

I'm not sure regarding which version did you use, because at some point of time we had the same problem, then update fixed it...

Your code works wrong for me also, but if I create class like

```
public class A
{
    public DateTimeOffset startDateTime;
}
```

and call

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<A>(content, jsonSerializerSettings);
```

everything works as expected. Yes, it's bug for sure, yes, I don't know how to get result exactly as YOU want, but probably, it will help for someone else.

Answer (score 8):

This works for me, a timezone is preserved

```
var jss = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
         DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat,
         DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Local, 
         DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.DateTimeOffset
    };
var responseObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(body, jss);
return responseObj.Select(s => new {
                    id = s["id"].Value<int>(),
                    date = s["date"].Value<DateTimeOffset>().DateTime,
                });
```

A JSON body is something like this

```
[
    {
        "id": 211,
        "date": "2017-10-22T12:00:00+03:00",
        "status": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 212,
        "date": "2017-10-28T12:00:00+03:00",
        "status": 1
    }
]
```

Comment: Confirmed this works perfectly, and I just switched out all my DateTime to DateTimeOffset .NET Core, and works perfectly. This answer should be higher up!

Answer (score 2):

To use the correct `Local Date` with custom `JsonConverter`, do:

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, type, new JsonSerializerSettings {
    DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat,
    DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Local,
    Converters = new JsonConverter[] { new MY_CUSTOM_CONVERTER() }
});
```

I search hard on the internet to combine them together, and eventually found `JsonConverter` can be feed into `JsonSerializerSettings`.

Answer (score 1):

As a simple way, you can Convert `Date` to `Ticks` for serializing and convert it from `Ticks` to `Date` for deserializing:

Serializing:

```
DateTime date = new DateTime();
ticks = date.Ticks
```

Deserializing"

```
Datetime = new Datetime(ticks);
```

Answer (score 0):

To use these settings in serializer, type:

```
var serializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat,
                DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Local
            };
            var serializer = JsonSerializer.Create(serializerSettings);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the only thing which worked for me (it differs from other supplied answers which didn't work). The key is DateParseHandling.None.

Previously JsonConvert.DeserializeObject was converting UK dates to US dates, even in hyphenated form. e.g. 2023-06-08 to 2023-08-06.

```
var jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat,
            DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Local,
            DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None
        };
```

then:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<*class*>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result, jsonSerializerSettings);
```