# How to deserialize "2015-02-02" to DateTimeOffset as UTC?

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

Is it possible to tell [Json.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/) to deserialize '2012-07-19' to a DateTimeOffset value with zero offset?

Code example to reproduce:

```
public class SingleDateTimeField
{
    public DateTimeOffset StartDateTime { get; set; }
}

[Test]
public void Convert()
{
    // Given
    var content = @"{""startDateTime"":""2012-07-19""}";
    var jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
    {
        DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat,
        DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.DateTimeOffset,
        DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc
    };

    // When
    var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SingleDateTimeField>(content, jsonSerializerSettings);

    // Then
    var expected = new DateTimeOffset(2012, 07, 19, 0, 0, 0, TimeSpan.Zero);
    Assert.That(obj.StartDateTime, Is.EqualTo(expected));

}
```

This fails with

> Expected: 2012-07-19 00:00:00.000+00:00
>   But was:  2012-07-19
>   00:00:00.000+03:00

Note that the timezone is +03:00

### Update:

I can get it working by using specialized converter (example below), but isnt the setting `DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc` supposed to already convert this UTC?  `AssumeUtc` converter should not be required.

```
public class AssumeUtc : IsoDateTimeConverter
{
    public AssumeUtc()
    {
        DateTimeStyles = System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal;
    }
}

public class SingleDateTimeField
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(AssumeUtc))]
    public DateTimeOffset StartDateTime { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does Json.NET DeserializeObject change the timezone to local time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11553760/why-does-json-net-deserializeobject-change-the-timezone-to-local-time)

Comment: you can create a custom deserializer for your property, or set a default custom deserializer when creating the serializer.  http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationAttributes.htm (look at JsonConverter attribute) and http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings.htm for setting defaults.

Comment: @CharlesMager that question deals with timezones. My question is about configuring serializer globally to treat all dates as UTC.

Comment: @ps2goat - you are right. I have already created `AssumeUtc` converter, that works great. My question is why do I have to use this given that I already configure serializer to user `DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc`. Shouldnt setting date time zone handling to UTC enough to make it work without converters?

Comment: Are you in, or is your machine set to, a UTC+3 timezone?

Comment: @ps2goat - yes, it is.  My expectation is that if `DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc` is set then it should ignore my time zone and deserialize into UTC time.

Comment: what version of json.net do you have?